# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 behind ARR reverse proxy

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, reverse-proxy

Has anyone successfully setup Sharepoint Foundation behind IIS ARR module's reverse proxy? I've been banging my head on the wall for hours now.

ATM, it's sort of working fine. Pages load up, and everything works (served from reverse proxy). The problem is the ajax calls (and some of the links as well I "think") are still going to the old side, and out going rewriting rule of the ARR doesn't seem to work either.

Help anyone?

Comment: Thanks Mike for adding the tag. Couldn't add it myself... >.> They really need to set the bar lower for the newer stackexchange sites. I'm so sure reverse-proxy is a common topic for SP.

Comment: did you manage to get an answer to this?
I'm trying to setup the same type of configuration.

Comment: @Jaepetto , yes I got it working. The trick is to use Alternate Access Mappings. Google up "Alternate Access Mappings" add the external url and it will work accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you setup your Reverse-Proxy to map requests from https://remote.domain.com to https://sharepoint.domain.local with “Forward the original Host header” turned on?

I know this is an option in TMG, not sure what would be the equivalent with your proxy

Comment: Doesn't seem like it.